# Error: composer require conedevelopment/bazar

Tags: php, laravel-8

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
 
   Problem 1
     - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-gd * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
   Problem 2
     - Root composer.json requires conedevelopment/bazar ^0.4.5 -> satisfiable by conedevelopment/bazar[v0.4.5].
     - conedevelopment/bazar v0.4.5 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
 
 To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
     - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
 You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
 Failed to update packages for  ./composer.json.
```

Comment: So check with your php.ini for these extensions as it says.

Comment: Pretty everything is already explained in the error message.  Obviously GD is missing. Edit php.ini and restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

When I went to install the Bazar library in a laravel project, I had this problem.

After googling, I got this solution.

Solving the error on **Windows 10 and PHP 8**. I followed these steps:

**Step 1:** `composer require "ext-gd:*" --ignore-platform-reqs`

**Step 2:** Abra o arquivo chamado **php.ini**, it is usually found in the following directory `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`

**Step 3:** With the file open you will have to search for
`;extension=gd` and update it to `extension=gd`